# Alternative website to WrapBootstrap (non-Bootstrap premium themes/templates)?

Tags: css, templates, themes

I am looking for an alternative premium theme/template selling website to WrapBootstrap. I like WrapBootstrap because you can purchase multi-install licenses (i.e. you are allowed to use the theme/template for multiple different websites/customers that you build a website for) for their themes and templates, but I don't like that all the themes are Bootstrap because then you are reliant on Bootstrap and thus all the negatives of Bootstrap (it's bloated, websites look similar, it doesn't follow best practices, etc). I believe it goes without saying that I would like attribution-free themes/templates.

So, I am wondering, does anyone know of a website similar to WrapBootstrap that sells affordable premium CSS (preferably HTML5+CSS3) themes/templates with multi-install licenses but that doesn't have themes/templates that all use Bootstrap?

Thanks!

edit: instead of downvoting my question and moving on, can you guys please inform me of why you are downvoting my question so I can know what I need to correct?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Hello, thank you for posting that. Since this is off-topic, which sister site of the StackExchange universe should this question be posted in?

Comment: I don't believe any are fitting for this type of question.  It's mostly considered opinionated and answers could become outdated eventually.

Comment: I see. That's kind of disappointing to hear, since I am pretty much asking for any and all websites that fit my criteria as it is hard to find any websites that do so and IMO with this type of question there's not really any room for opinion since I am just asking for as many websites as possible and opinions don't really factor into that. Technically any content on this website could become outdated which is why revisions/edits are allowed.

Answer (score 3):

https://html5up.net and http://www.styleshout.com  is a good alternative which I use.

Answer (score 1):

So, I have found at one website so far that meets my criteria.

I have found Pixelarity (pixelarity.com) which allows you to use licenses for multiple installations, and the themes/templates do not rely on Bootstrap.

I would still absolutely appreciate any other answers.